# Extract dict of list in Pyspark DF

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark

I have a pyspark df composed of two column id and customfields. Id is an integer and Custom fields are string column.

Schema:

root

|-- Id: integer (nullable = true)

|-- CustomFields: string (nullable = true)

Table:

| Id | CustomFields |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | [{'CustomFieldId': 1, 'Value': 'yes', 'Name': 'isDog'}, {'CustomFieldId': 0, 'Value': 'no', 'Name': 'isCat'}] |
| 2 |  |
| 3 | [{'CustomFieldId': 121, 'Value': 'yes', 'Name': 'canFly'}, {'CustomFieldId': 0, 'Value': 'no', 'Name': 'isCat'}] |

I want to extract only isCat column and generate new column based on value. If there is no data in customFields I need to set as no as well.
Desired table:

| ID | CustomFields | isCat |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | [{'CustomFieldId': 1, 'Value': 'yes', 'Name': 'isDog'}, {'CustomFieldId': 0, 'Value': 'no', 'Name': 'isCat'}] | no |
| 2 |  | no |
| 3 | [{'CustomFieldId': 121, 'Value': 'yes', 'Name': 'isCat'}, {'CustomFieldId': 0, 'Value': 'no', 'Name': 'canFly'}] | no |

Thanks in advance.

I first converted CustomFields(string) to appropriate json in order to extract values from them.

```
        df_ld = df_ld.withColumn(
            "CustomFields", F.regexp_replace("CustomFields", "None", "null")
        )
        df_ld = df_ld.withColumn("CustomFields", F.translate("CustomFields", "'", '"'))
```

Then tried to extract with  getItem() functions but I do not find any way to produce.

Answer (score 0):

#### Code

```
# Parse json into array of maps
col = F.from_json('CustomFields', 'array<map<string, string>>')

# Filter the array and select the map where Name = 'isCat', 
# then use indexing to extract Value
val = F.filter(col, lambda c: c['Name'] == 'isCat')[0]['Value']

# Fill the null values
df = df.withColumn('isCat', F.when(val.isNull(), 'no').otherwise(val))
```

#### Result

```
+---+----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+-----+
|Id |CustomFields                                                                                                    |isCat|
+---+----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+-----+
|1  |[{'CustomFieldId': 1, 'Value': 'yes', 'Name': 'isDog'}, {'CustomFieldId': 0, 'Value': 'no', 'Name': 'isCat'}]   |no   |
|2  |                                                                                                                |no   |
|3  |[{'CustomFieldId': 121, 'Value': 'yes', 'Name': 'canFly'}, {'CustomFieldId': 0, 'Value': 'no', 'Name': 'isCat'}]|no   |
+---+----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+-----+
```